# rospkg not found in fuerte

Tags: ros, rospkg, pythonpath, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

trying to use

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/scripts/view_frames", line 43, in <module>  
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)   
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>  
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest  
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>  
    import rospkg  
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

...but I cannot find any errors around my environmental variables.. :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192701/rospkg-not-found-in-fuerte/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this question has been answered before:

http://answers.ros.org/question/39657/importerror-no-module-named-rospkg/

---

Originally posted by [Pep Lluis Negre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4205/pep-lluis-negre/) with karma: 111 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0